# Использование .so библиотек в системном приложении

Tags: java, android, jni, права-доступа

Есть приложение, которое мы подписали ключом, которым подписаны все системные приложения. Это приложение установлено в `/system/priv-app`.

В приложении имеются `.so` файлы в папке **jniLibs**.

Подключаю так:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.so'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Правильно ли я подключаю к проекту `.so` библиотеки? Может я что-то не так делаю?

При инициализации библиотеки которая использует эти `.so` файлы, наше приложение падает. Ошибка вот такая:

```
System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load HypSdkJni
from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
"/system/priv-app/appname.apk", zip file
"/data/user/0/ru.pack.appname/code_cache/secondary-dexes/appname.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
 /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Получается пытается распаковать в папку `/system/lib` - но не хватает прав на это? Или что не так?

Если приложение установить как обычное приложение в `data/app` - то все нормально работает..

Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается так что, если приложение устанавливается в System раздел то нужно позаботиться чтобы все .so библиотеки были положены в папку /system/lib

Если вы используете какие то сторонние библиотеки и они внутри себя используют **.so** библиотеки то нужно позаботится и о них(вытащить их и положить в папку /system/lib) !

Answer (score 0):

В проекте для Android Studio создаете папки
/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
(armeabi-v7a - может быть другая в зависимости от архитектуры).
Туда копируете вашу библиотеку, обновляете проект если открыт.
В Gradle ничего прописывать не надо.

Comment: Ок. Это понял. Так и есть, почти.  Знаете в чем у меня может быть проблема?