# Отладка библиотеки SO в Android Studio без исходного кода приложения

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, отладка

Мне нужно написать библиотеку ссылок SO для приложения. APK для приложения есть, но нет исходного кода. Библиотеку получается успешно собрать и она работает, но хотелось бы отладить некоторые моменты. Я могу отладить DLL в Visual Studio — там есть символы отладки и подключение к процессу. Как сделать что-то подобное в Android Studio? Может кто подскажет как все это сделать?

Я не очень опытный пользователь Android Studio, но возникла такая проблема и прошу помощи. Уже три недели пытаюсь разобраться и безуспешно

**UPDATE 1**

[image: Присоединение к процессу]

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956719/311415

Comment: В андроид все то же самое - отладочные символы и подключение к процессу

Comment: @Style-7 обязательно попробую, спасибо. А как присоединиться к процессу? Видел, что в Android Studio можно выбрать приложение, к которому можно присоединиться, но приложение, для которого пишу библиотеку, не отображается там. Или это не совсем то?

Comment: К какому процессу вы собрались присоединяться в Linux?

Comment: @Style-7 Отредактировал вопрос (UPDATE 1). Извиняюсь: не процесс (хотя так и называется), а приложение. Я выбираю приложение для присоединения и его отладки. Или это именно для отладки APK, но не библиотек?